# Floating problems on Chrome. I have two floated columns but, on Chrome, the second colums appear under the first one

Tags: html, css, css-float, wordpress-theming

I have modify a WordPress template adding at the content zone an other column.

As you can see here: http://scorejava.com/wordpress351/ the content zone for the articles contain two columns (the first that show the last posts inserted, and the second one that show the most read posts)

To do this I simply have created two div in the **index.php** wordpress template file having respectively **id="column1"** and **id="column2"**

Then in the **style.css** file of my template I have declared the following properties for these divs elements:

```
#column1{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#column2{
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

To floating on the left the column1 div and have the column2 on its right.

In Firefox seems work well (I have test it on Firefx 19.0.2 on my Ubuntu) but if I open it using **Chrome** this is not true and the column2 div appear under the column1 div slightly shifted to the right respect to the latter...

why? I have try to find a solution but I have no more ideas (I am not so good with CSS)

Can you help me to solve this problem on Chrome browser?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Works fine for me as long as the width's are set as 300px. Looking at both the widths I can see they're showing as 50%?

Comment: Ah, I have do an error posting a snippet code of a wrong style.css file...I have edited it using the correct one...
What do you mean with: "Works fine for me as long as the width's are set as 300px" ? What width do you mean?

Comment: When viewing your code I noticed it was different to the code you had posted. Take a look at reply below. Should help you out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross-browser easy solution:

```
#column1 {
    width: 48%;
}
#column2 {
    width: 48%;
    padding-left: 4%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set the width of each column to `50%`, so the proper width of right column is `50%` plus `padding-left: 30px`. What you need to do is set `box-sizing: border-box` and it should be fine. Read more [here](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

Keep in mind, that it won;t work in lt IE8.

Comment: mmm, I still having some problem. I have adding box-sizing: border-box property into both div property definition and now column2 appear on the right of column2 but doing so I obtain that I have not space beetwen the column1 and the column2 (I have also try to add margin but the two columns remain attached)

Comment: Yes, because now both colums take exactly 50% of theirs parent space, so there's no room for additional space. I think the best solution is @riverstorm 's one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the following if you want a 30px margin between the columns:

```
#column1, #column2{
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#column1{
    padding-right:15px;
}

#column2{
    padding-left:15px;
}
```

The `box-sizing` property makes sure you can add padding to an element without changing its width. Normally an element's width is calculated like this: `total width` = `width` + `padding`, with `box-sizing:border-box` this becomes `total width` = `width`